# Is "escapeshellarg" safe enough?

Tags: php, security, exec, youtube-dl

Scenario:

1. user enters video url
2. php downloads video with `exec( "youtube-dl " . escapeshellarg($url) );`

Question:

Is it safe enough?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`escapeshellarg` prevents the *shell* from misinterpreting your command-line, so you're safe there. However, you're still passing in user input to youtube-dl. While this is not a security risk, it will fail in certain cases. You want to add `--` to make sure that the user's input is a URL and not an option:

```
exec( "youtube-dl -- " . escapeshellarg($url) );
```

This will also fix problems where the "URL" starts with a dash. For example, `-8F4YF_pH-4` is a valid YouTube video ID.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's is safe enough. You can check it's working.

`escapeshellarg()` adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument. This function should be used to escape individual arguments to shell functions coming from user input.

```
$arg = 'test\'test';
echo escapeshellarg($arg);
```

It will show `'test'\''test'` as output . so you can't trick it.